# What is UCRTBASE error in dependency walker?

Tags: dll, ocx, dependency-walker

I have an OCX file that not register in another PC. when I run `dependencyWalker.exe` and load the OCX on it, It shows me some dll is missing. I downloaded some of them from [DLL-File.com](https://www.dll-files.com/) but It shows me UCRTBASE error. what is it? How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: It is just one more way in which Depends cannot provide you with good information.  It has not been maintained in a very long time and doesn't know anything about these api-ms-win-xxx [MinWin forwarders](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060719-24/?p=30473).  Ucrtbase.dll is normally deployed through Windows Update, if it is *really* missing (belongs in system32 and syswow64) then it is best to stay far away from that machine.  *Never* copy files from virus distribution centers like dll-file.com, reformatting the disk on that machine is best.

Answer (score 0):

What Windows version are you targeting? For Win10 ucrtbase is indeed deployed as part of the OS, for 7/8 you need to [install the VS2015 redist](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

As for the api-ms-win-*** dll's, these are actually not MinWin forwarders but rather [API sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn933214), sometimes referred to as 'virtual dlls' - essentially, an extra level of indirection gradually introduced since Vista to isolate kernel functionality moving among components. I came across software that was deployed with physical dlls implementing the API sets (as your ocx seem to be), but much more often applications resort to the built in OS apparatus - [embedded in the Windows Loader itself](https://ofekshilon.com/2016/03/27/on-api-ms-win-xxxxx-dll-and-other-dependency-walker-glitches/), and not requiring any real dlls for operation.